# Determining if a number is odd or even in Lua

Tags: lua

I need to compare a user inputed number to determine if it is odd or even.  I am using Lua and so far I have no code... all i know is that i would like to use this in an if else statement formatted as such...

```
    if (number is even) then
        -block of code
    else
        -block of code
    end
```

any help or advice anyone can give would be great!

Comment: I don't know LUA, but the `%` (modulus) operator is often used for this. A bitwise-and (often `&`) of the lowest-bit is also an option in some languages.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
if (number % 2 == 0) then
    .....it is even
else
    .....it is odd
end
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `math.mod(number, 2) == 0`

Comment: AFAIK, `math.mod` is undocumented equivalent of `%` (which also works with floats), retained for backward compatibility or something like that.

Comment: you are right. It also has been renamed to math.fmod according to the [Lua 5.2 Reference Manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.1) so Antons approach seems to be the better solution.

Comment: the [Lua online interpreter](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo) fails at `7.3 % 2` but `math.fmod(7.3,2)` return 1.3

Comment: @kphilipp, try `return 7.3 % 2` or `=7.3 % 2`in the Lua online interpreter, just like the command-line one.